# "One-size-smaller than the accompanying font size" command

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, chapters, fontsize

I want to make a subtitle for a chapter, having `\Large` as the chapter's title font size; so I'd write it as

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Title \\ {\large Subtitle}}
\end{document}
```

This would make the subtitle's font size look good where the title is, but look horrific in the toc. So I'm asking, is there any kind of command or workaround so that will decrease subtitle's font size by one size, in both occasions? From `\Large` to `\large` in the chapter and from `\normalsize` to `\small` in the toc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy fix is to use the optional "short title" parameter of the `\chapter` command:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter[Title \\ {\small Subtitle}]{Title \\ {\large Subtitle}}
\end{document}
```

For the general solution to font sizes relative to the current one you can use the `relsize` package (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70227/36686) for a related question).

Personally I would not be very happy introducing so much style-dependent formatting in titles; if this situation is not an exception but the norm I would define my own sectioning style, maybe with the help of the `titlesec` package and custom macros for title+subtitle chapters.