# Adjusting vertical separation of footnote mark

Tags: fonts, superscripts

I'm using a devanagari font to typeset in Sanskrit language. The font which I use is Sanskrit 2003.

The problem with this and other few similar fonts is that the footnote mark is not enough vertical separation. It appears to alighn it's top with the top of the text. I'll like to have it's bottom align with top of the text.

MWE is this(XeLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{sanskrit}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,Ligatures=TeX,AutoFakeBold=3.5,AutoFakeSlant,WordSpace=1, Scale=1.4]{Sanskrit 2003}
\newfontfamily{\devanagarifont}[Script=Devanagari,Ligatures=TeX,AutoFakeBold=3.5,AutoFakeSlant,WordSpace=1, Scale=1.4]{Sanskrit 2003}
%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
%%make all Arabic/Roman numerals Devanagari
\makeatletter
\def\devanagarinumber#1{\devanagaridigits{\number #1}}
\let\orig@arabic\@arabic
\let\@arabic\devanagarinumber
\makeatother

%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
\begin{document}
        नत्वा श्रीगणनाथपादकमलं प्रत्यूहकक्षानलं\\
        मार्त्तण्डं भवमेश\footnote{
            भवश्च मेशश्च भवमेशः ।
        }%
        पादयुगलं देव्यङ्घ्रिपद्मावल(लि?)म्
        ।\\
        लब्धं यत्पदसेवनेन सकलं वेदान्तवाचाम्फलं\\
        तं कैलासपदादिसञ्ज्ञमचलं\footnote{
            कैलासपर्व्वत इति वा कैलासगिरिः इति वा गुरुनाम स्यात् ।
        }
        संस्मृत्य लब्ध्वा बलम् ॥१॥
\end{document}
```

[image: PDF with Sanskrit 2003 font]

If I use a different font, I get a little different result. But, that's also not satisfactory.
Here is the result with Kokila font.
[image: PDF with Kokila font]

================================================

**SOLUTION**

As suggested by @Ulrike Fischer, the problem was that I was scaling only some fonts. So, I removed the individual scaling, used [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70227/how-to-scale-all-fonts-in-the-whole-document-by-certain-factor-or-percentage) to learn scaling, and then using package `relsize` and applying scaling in the begining of the document produced the result.

[image: Correct result with package relsize]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are scaling the text font but don't adjust the math font, and as superscript uses math mode, it is too small. Better use a large fontsize instead:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=15pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\makeatletter
\setdefaultlanguage{sanskrit}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,Ligatures=TeX,AutoFakeBold=3.5,AutoFakeSlant,WordSpace=1]{Sanskrit 2003}
\newfontfamily{\devanagarifont}[Script=Devanagari,Ligatures=TeX,AutoFakeBold=3.5,AutoFakeSlant,WordSpace=1]{Sanskrit 2003}
%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
%%make all Arabic/Roman numerals Devanagari
\makeatletter
\def\devanagarinumber#1{\devanagaridigits{\number #1}}
\let\orig@arabic\@arabic
\let\@arabic\devanagarinumber
\makeatother
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
\begin{document}
        नत्वा श्रीगणनाथपादकमलं प्रत्यूहकक्षानलं\\
        मार्त्तण्डं भवमेश\footnote{
            भवश्च मेशश्च भवमेशः ।
        }%
        पादयुगलं देव्यङ्घ्रिपद्मावल(लि?)म्
        ।\\
        लब्धं यत्पदसेवनेन सकलं वेदान्तवाचाम्फलं\\
        तं कैलासपदादिसञ्ज्ञमचलं\footnote{
            कैलासपर्व्वत इति वा कैलासगिरिः इति वा गुरुनाम स्यात् ।
        }
        संस्मृत्य लब्ध्वा बलम् ॥१॥ $a=b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think that the solution works, but I'll like to know a way to customize the separation of footenotemark.
Although the sample worked for me, when I implemented to my original work and changed the document class to scrbook, compilation became difficult. Sometimes polyglossia didn't see devanagarifonts provided, sometimes editing title with titlesec was broken.
So, I was unable to apply this solution.